# How does one transition from two layers of drywall?

Tags: drywall, garage

I am in the process of finishing my garage. Common walls with the house have two layers of drywall: ~1/2" and 5/8". Is there a cheap and aesthetically pleasing way to transition to one layer of 5/8" for the remainder of the wall or will the whole wall have to be 1-1/8" thick? I could install OSB behind the drywall which would be nice for hanging stuff; however, it's pretty expensive right now.[image: two layers of drywall]

Comment: Why not just rip the 1/2" OSB into 1-1/2 wide strips to use as shims, and attach them to the edge of the wall studs?

Comment: @Tag- I'm not quiet positive on this, but the thickness on the common wall may be due to a fire rating code requiring a certain thickness. Maybe some one else will ring in. Just tossing suggestions out.

Comment: @ojait, I don't think OP is planning to remove the existing fire rated wall, but is trying to match the surface level on an *adjoining* part of the same wall that is not "common" to both the garage and house... at least that's how I read the question. Good to bring up the fire rating requirement though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just rip the 1/2" OSB into 1-1/2 wide strips to use as shims, and attach them to the edge of the wall studs?

Comment: This ended up working great. If I had known how much time it was going to take to rip and install ~100' of OSB I'd have paid to use full sheets. With that being said I learned a lot and am pretty happy with the result. Thank you!